# Grid Queue size becomes double when nodes are busy

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium4

We are running automation test cases in GRID, when all the nodes are busy, queue doubles and finally fails with

```
Failed to invoke configuration method setupDriver:Could not start a new session. Unable to parse remote response:

<title>504 Gateway Time-out</title>
504 Gateway Time-out

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Unable to parse remote response:

<title>504 Gateway Time-out</title>
504 Gateway Time-out

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:130)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:547)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
My Questions are as follows
```

How to disable the retry in Queue if a session is not found?
How to increase the Queue Wait time until the node is free

[image]

My Questions are as follows

How to disable the retry in Queue if a session is not found?
How to increase the Queue Wait time until the node is free